# Re-parenting entitlements

Tags: apex

The standard `Entitlement` object is a child of the `Account` (master) object. Is it possible to re-parent `Entitlement` records to another `Account`? Are there limitations around re-parenting the `Entitlement` record?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this directly because `Entitlement.AccountId` is not an updateable field

[See Apex SObjects Doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_entitlement.htm?search_text=contact):

[image]

This is similar to the issue of changing the Product on an existing `OpportunityLineItem` by changing `PricebookEntryId` - the system doesn't support this.

A workaround is to clone the `Entitlement` (i.e. insert a new one pointing at the correct AccountId) and delete the old one.

Comment: Hi @cropredy , thanks for the info on this. It's strange, I was able to run a script in dev console and update the accountId on the entitlement to a new account. Has the accountId properties on the entitlement object changed to be updateable?

Comment: not as per v39.0 docs (which are in preview). If you are observing success, the doc could be in error